# React Native / Expo input lags on more than one TextInput

Tags: react-native, expo

I have been trying to fix this weird problem I am facing with React Native/Expo. I was working on an Authentication page. It is a simple username and password input form. It was going okay for a few weeks until yesterday when the `TextInput` component started lagging. The weird part is it only lags in my device (Iphone X). When I use a virtual device, it runs fine and there is no lagging when I input something in the `TextInput`.

I also want to mention that it is not just my code but if a component has more than once `TextInput`, the `TextInput` becomes laggy and super slow when anything is typed.

I have tried:

- Restarting my phone
- Deleting the expo app and downloading it again
- Running the app in production mode

Nothing seems to work and the component is still lagging. Has anyone else faced such problem? I have created this simple snack:

https://snack.expo.io/@ayushdev/9d2af8

The issue still persist in this simple snack too.

Answer (score 0):

You should try state colocation here. Other things constant, that is expected to give you at least some speedup.

Separate out the different InputText components in your form, each updating their own states only. This ensures that the entire form is not re-rendered as you change the input in just one of those fields.